# sql statement works in phpMyAdmin but won't work in mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Really stuck on something. I'm trying to update a database and the code looks write - and if I echo it out and paste it directly into phpMyAdmin it works perfectly - but the code itself doesn't work... I have spend a day so far trying to figure out why it's not working and I'm completely out of ideas...

```
function restoreSession() 
{

mysql_connect("theHost", "root", "rootPWD") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("myDatabase") or die(mysql_error());    

$restore_cmd = 'UPDATE wp_dor_cart66_sessions SET user_data = (SELECT user_data FROM wp_dor_cart66_stored_sessions WHERE ip_address = "' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '")';

$clean_up = "DELETE FROM `wp_dor_cart66_sessions` WHERE `ip_address` = \"" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\" AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM ( SELECT id FROM `wp_dor_cart66_sessions` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ) user_data )";

mysql_query($clean_up) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error()); 
$result = mysql_query($restore_cmd) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error()); 
echo "<br/>";
echo $restore_cmd;
echo "<br/>";
var_dump($result);
echo "<br/>";
print_r($result);
}
```

The resulting output looks like:

```
UPDATE wp_dor_cart66_sessions SET user_data = 
(SELECT user_data FROM   wp_dor_cart66_stored_sessions 
WHERE ip_address = "196.54.110.24");

bool(true)

1
```

It doesn't appear to have any errors - but I just can't get it to update. If it didn't work in phpMyAdmin - I'd know there was something wrong with the SQL - but it seems right... I'm just really out of ideas - any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Here are the statements again with some formatting:

```
$restore_cmd = '
    UPDATE
        wp_dor_cart66_sessions
    SET
        user_data = (
            SELECT
                user_data
            FROM
                wp_dor_cart66_stored_sessions
            WHERE
                ip_address = "' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '"
        )
';

$clean_up = "
    DELETE FROM
        `wp_dor_cart66_sessions`
    WHERE
        `ip_address` = \"" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\"
        AND id NOT IN (
            SELECT
                id
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        id
                    FROM
                        `wp_dor_cart66_sessions`
                    ORDER BY
                        id DESC
                    LIMIT
                        1
                ) user_data
        )
";
```

Comment: May be it's just me (quite likey today) but how's the second query (DELETE ... NOT IN ... ) supposed to work?

Comment: Thanks! That formatting is much easier to read. How the delete statement works is that it selects all the sessions that have a certain ip address and then it deletes everything that is not in a selection - and the selection has a limit of 1. So it deletes everything except the most recent record... I have tested the delete a few times and it has worked so far...

Comment: But shouldn't the inner select somehow be related to the ip address (i.e. select the group-wise maximum for ip=remote_addr)? Right now it's not, it always selects the highest id of _all_ records in wp_dor_cart66_sessions.

Comment: Yes - you are correct.  I noticed that after I posted - definitely an oversight on my part. What I have done since I posted is simplified both sql commands. The delete now deletes all the records associated with the ip_address then I create a new record with the same session_id as the newest record (which just got deleted) and then add the user_data I want that way. It seems to be working so far - for some reason the UPDATE command just would work... but thank you very much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$restore_cmd = 'UPDATE wp_dor_cart66_sessions SET user_data = (SELECT user_data FROM wp_dor_cart66_stored_sessions WHERE ip_address = \"' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '\")';
```

need to escape the quotation marks

Comment: I tried that before... add the slashes makes it error out... I've literally tried every combination I can think of as far as quotes and escape characters goes... nothing works as of yet - thanks anyways though...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like quoting error, Try this:

```
"UPDATE wp_dor_cart66_sessions SET user_data = (SELECT user_data FROM wp_dor_cart66_stored_sessions WHERE ip_address = '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "')";
```

Comment: Good suggestion - but same result. It worked in so far as it didn't error out but nothing was updated in the database... I pasted the echo'd out result into phpMyAdmin and it worked no problem however... which is why this is such a mystery...

Comment: Does $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] return what you expect?

Comment: Yes - it was returning what I was expecting. I did eventually get this working - as described above - by simplifying the sql commands...

Answer (score 0):

If could be that you have multiple results in your SELECT.
What if you do ...

```
$restore_cmd = 'UPDATE wp_dor_cart66_sessions SET user_data = (SELECT user_data FROM wp_dor_cart66_stored_sessions WHERE ip_address = "' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '" LIMIT 1)';
```

... note the LIMIT 1

Comment: Interesting suggestion... there should never be more than one result though - because the query before that deletes all but the newest row. I tried it but unfortunately same result - nothing happened...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the first query is not deleting all the matching rows?

I don't understand the "user_data" part at the end of the first query. But I would check the number of affected rows after each query to see if query is doing any affect on data and if it is, is it doing well or there's just some logical mistake.

Comment: That's a interesting idea but I'm pretty sure that's not the case. I have commented out the delete line before - to ensure nothing was getting deleted - and it still didn't work...